# Struggling to click the load more button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I plan to build a scraper that'll utilize both Selenium and BeautifulSoup.

I'm struggling to click the load more button with selenium. I've managed to detect the button, scroll to it etc. - can't seem to figure out a way to continuously click the button.

Any suggestions on how to pass this hurdle?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def search_agent(zip):
    location = bot.find_element_by_name('hheroquotezip')
    time.sleep(3)
    location.clear()
    location.send_keys(zip)
    location.submit()


def load_all_agents():
    # click more until no more results to load
    while True:
        try:
            #more_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'results.length'))).click()
            more_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[3]/button'))).click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break

    # wait for results to load
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.seclection-result .partners-detail')))

    print ("Complete")
    bot.quit()

#define Zip for search query
zip = 20855

bot = webdriver.Safari()
wait = WebDriverWait(bot, 10)


#fetch agents page
bot.get('https://www.erieinsurance.com/find-an-insurance-agent')
search_agent(zip)
load_all_agents()
```

With the above approach, the console spits out these errors:

[Error] Refused to load [https://9203275.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=9203275;type=agent0;cat=agent0;ord=7817740349177;gtm=2wg783;auiddc=373080108.1594822533;~oref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.erieinsurance.com%2Ffind-an-insurance-agent-results%3Fzipcode%3D20855](https://9203275.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=9203275;type=agent0;cat=agent0;ord=7817740349177;gtm=2wg783;auiddc=373080108.1594822533;%7Eoref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.erieinsurance.com%2Ffind-an-insurance-agent-results%3Fzipcode%3D20855)? because it does not appear in the frame-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
[Error] Refused to connect to https://api.levelaccess.net/analytics/3.0/results because it does not appear in the connect-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Comment: Hi Edan - how is it struggling? What's the error? what's happening(or not happening?)

Comment: Hey Rich - I seem to be able to recognize the button in various methods used. The struggle has been to actually simulate the click behavior. I've managed to either scroll down to the button or go to it by detection of the button. But can't seem to figure out how to actually click.

Comment: what with `.click()` ? Do you get error ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I just ran your code with chrome - without the beautiful soup import and it worked fine. clicked the load more button every time.... failed after that but still worked on the bit you're struggling with

Comment: when I use your code with Firefox then it clicks all buttons "Show More Agents" and finally there is no more button "Show More Agents"

Comment: Considering @furas seems similar to me - could this be a safari issue?

Comment: Really?! So maybe this is something particular with Safari? I just added to the question the errors I'm seeing in console (in safari)

Comment: I think (similar to @RichEdwards) that it is only problem with Safari. But I don't have it confirm it. Maybe it is some adblock  or some security system which is used only when Selenium controls browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an answer to post a couple of images.

- When i ran the attached script in chrome it worked fine.
- When @furas did the same in firefox he had the same result
- I ran the same script 10 times back to back and i wasn't refused.

What i note based on the error is that iframe seems broswer sensitive:

In Chrome this header contains chromium scripts:
[image: Chrome devtools]

In Firefox it contains no scripts:
[image: firefox devtools]

Have a look and see what you get manually in your safari.

A simple answer might be to not use safari - use chrome or FF. Is that an option?  (if it *MUST* be safari just say and i'll look again.)

Finally - couple of quick additional notes.

The site is using angular, so you might want to consider protractor if you're struggling with synchronisation. (protractor helps with some script-syncing capailies)

Also worth a note - don't feel you have to land on the home page and then navigate as user. Update your URL to the search results page and feed in the zip code and save yourself some time:

```
https://www.erieinsurance.com/find-an-insurance-agent-results?zipcode=20855
```

---

[edit/update]
This the same thing? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/458
Closed bug in 2016 around "Content Security Policies" - logged as an apple thing.

Comment: This is awesome, Rich! Thanks a ton :)
I don't have to use Safari. To save myself from the headache and carry on with my learning journey I'll go ahead and use Chrome. I just installed the driver and it does work until it times out.
I'll also implement a question of what zip code to fetch and then go directly there, as you suggested. 

Again, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: no worries at all - just good timing that i had 5 minutes to have a look. Just mark the answer as the right one so others can learn from it and job done!